# How to declare a property which will be lately initialized in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

How do I make my ArrayAdapter for a ListView global in the MainActivity ?

my code is:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

var listItems = ArrayList<String>()
private var listAdapter: ArrayAdapter<String>? = null


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

    listAdapter = ArrayAdapter(
        this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
        listItems
    )
    listfield.adapter = listAdapter
    listAdapter.add("Hello World!")
    listAdapter.add("RFID app")
```

So the problem is this gives an error at compile-time:
*Smart cast to ArrayAdapter is impossible because 'listAdapter' is a mutable property that could have been changed by this time.*
This would be because there is no way of knowing if another thread has set the listAdapter back to null when .Add is called.

I need the listAdapter to be global because I need to call .notifyDataSetChanged() from a call-back function (when a barcode had been read by the barcode-reader) and if I declare the listAdapter in onCreate() it is not available to the call-back function. So it needs to be a property.
Kotlin complains that a property must either be initialized or declared as 'abstract'. Obviously 'abstract' won't work here, but I can't initialize it as other than "null" either as initialization requires the context and the context is not available until onCreate().
How would one go about this in Kotlin?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A better approach would be to declare `listAdapter` as `lateinit`

change it to :

```
private lateinit var listAdapter: ArrayAdapter<String>
```

Comment: I thought OP wanted the listAdapter to be globally available to other classes too, but this answer is correct :P

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. Thanks!
I realize using the word "Global" was incorrect here as I was ok using the private modifier. I only needed it available to other functions than onCreate inside MainActivity.

Answer (score 0):

That happens because Kotlin has no way of telling if the property is null or not, you have 2 choices to fix the error:

1. add `!!` operator that will throw error if the variable is null, example: `listAdapter!!.add("Hello World!")`
2. use the lateinit option. This option is better since in your case the adapter can never be null.

Comment: Thanks for the added bit about the !! option, although I went with the lateinit

Comment: in this case lateinit is the way to go, in other cases when you deal with nullable values operators `!!` and `?` are the way to go.